# to read an array of object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am try to read an object from an Array. 
pVal is my array of objects. 
I need to get the value of "group" depending on value of id. 
I want to display, if the id is 1 , it should display "VKC", need help here.

This is code I tried

```
this.arr = userData; // -> json
this.pId = this.arr.pId; // value is 1 or 2 or 3 

pVal: Array<Object> = [{id:1, group:'VKC'},
{id:2, group:'ABC'}, 
{id:10, group:'DEF'},
{id:3, group:'GHI'},
{id:5, group:'JKL'},]

alert(this.pVal['1'].group);
this.pInd = this.pVal[this.pId].group;
```

Comment: try something like this: `alert(this.pVal.filter(item => item.id == 1)[0].group)`

Comment: but it's not a good code, it's just to your test. I think the best approach is use the `switch` statement. I'll give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

> if the id is 1, it should display "VKC"

The rule for what to display is already part of the object. If you only want to display id 1, you can do something like this:

```
for(let obj of this.pVal){
   if(obj.id === 1)
      alert(obj.group);
}
```